# Generate a report every 10 minutes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables temperature and pressure with readings as shown below my first table generates a value every 10 minutes

The first table contains the following data:

```
Temperature          Time             Date 
28.8      1900-01-01 13:14:54.000   2011-05-25 00:00:00
29.1      1900-01-01 13:15:04.000   2011-05-25 00:00:00
29.4      1900-01-01 13:15:14.000   2011-05-25 00:00:00
29.7      1900-01-01 13:15:24.000   2011-05-25 00:00:00
30        1900-01-01 13:15:34.000   2011-05-25 00:00:00
30.3      1900-01-01 13:15:44.000   2011-05-25 00:00:00
30.6      1900-01-01 13:15:54.000   2011-05-25 00:00:00
30.9      1900-01-01 13:16:04.000   2011-05-25 00:00:00
31.2      1900-01-01 13:16:14.000   2011-05-25 00:00:00
```

My second table generates a value every 20 minutes and i'm storing this value in the database i.e Sql Server

The second table contains

```
Pressure         Time                  Date
0.9 1900-01-01 13:14:04.000 2011-05-25 00:00:00
1.7 1900-01-01 13:14:24.000 2011-05-25 00:00:00
2.5 1900-01-01 13:14:44.000 2011-05-25 00:00:00
3.3 1900-01-01 13:15:04.000 2011-05-25 00:00:00
4.1 1900-01-01 13:15:24.000 2011-05-25 00:00:00
4.9 1900-01-01 13:15:44.000 2011-05-25 00:00:00
5.7 1900-01-01 13:16:04.000 2011-05-25 00:00:00
6.5 1900-01-01 13:16:24.000 2011-05-25 00:00:00
7.3 1900-01-01 13:16:44.000 2011-05-25 00:00:00
```

I would like my output to return:

```
Date          Time       Temperature   Pressure
25/05/2011   13:14:54     28.8           0
25/05/2011   13:15:04     29.1           3.3
25/05/2011   13:15:14     29.4           0
25/05/2011   13:15:24     29.7           4.1
```

And so on and the user will select particular date on that that date what are the readings are there it should dispaly for example if he select 25/05/2011 that reading should be displayed. I have to bind this result to a gridview using C#.

Comment: Where does the 2nd row in your output come from please? And why mention 5/10 minutes when your input data is not at these intervals. If you want help, provide **correct** examples...

Comment: my 2nd row output comes from my second table,my first table contains 5minutes data and second table contains 10minutes data i ahve to compare both table value if i have data in that interval i have to fetch from that table,i have jst guven sample interval

Comment: @Sweety: no, it doesn't. Where is "13:05:15"? Like I said, provide **correct** examples. We shouldn't have to guessing what you mean

Comment: If your output should be between input values, so why output is so short? Why in second row pressure=0 (not 30)?

We can not help you if you do not give to us precisely described your logic.

Comment: -1 for wasting time. With a proper question you'd have had the answer within minutes. And you mean seconds not minutes...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind about possible gaps for missing datetime records, a `FULL OUTER JOIN` would suffice.

```
SELECT  ISNULL(t1.Date, t2.Date)
        , ISNULL(t1.Time, t2.Time)
        , ISNULL(t1.Temperature, 0)
        , ISNULL(t2.Pressure, 0)
FROM    Table1 t1
        FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Date = t1.Date AND t2.Time = t1.Time
```

Comment: @Sweety: Please mark the question as answered if it has solved your problem to ensure people get credit for their work/help.

Comment: @Tom pickles:where should i go and make it has answered

Comment: @Sweety, click on the tick symbol next to the answer you choose.

Comment: @Tom, @Sweety - thank you. @Sweety: gbn has a point. You would have saved yourself quite some time by asking the correct question to start with. As you are a new user to the site, welcome to SO and if you give SO a chance, you will notice we can learn a lot from each other.

Comment: @Sweety, you can but better might be to ask a new question. A new question would attrack others from the community whereas posting in comments, it's only the two of us.

Comment: @lieven:k i have posted it now.